# This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement (ExpoKit)

Tags: react-native, expo

Warning in Google Play:

This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement

The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 1.

From August 1, 2019 all releases must be compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement.

Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device architecture receives only the native code it needs. This avoids increasing the overall size of your app.

How to fix this problem?

What I have already tried is to add `ndk.abiFilters` `in gradle`
ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'

when I created apk, app started crashing immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You have to upgrade your react native. For expo follow [react native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading). For react native **without expo** You can use these commands:

```
sudo npm install -g react-native-git-upgrade
```

Then

```
react-native-git-upgrade
```

Comment: So you want to say that when I will upgrade react-native to the latest version, it will create app compliant with Google Play 64-bit requirements automatically?

Comment: Please check my updated answer. 
Yes. Be relax. I tried it yesterday. +1

Comment: Does this solution work normally with apps running 'ExpoKit'?

Comment: Yes. For upgrading expo you can follow react native docs that linked to my answer. please +1

Comment: I found in the official react-native blog, that this issue was really solved in 0.59, however, as far I understood, expo is not supporting now 0.59, I was trying to upgrade to 0.59 and got this error https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25003